# my result only get 1 data, can you help me for get more data and save another file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'http://h1.nobbd.de/index.php?start='
for page in range(1,10):   
    req = requests.get(URL + str(page) + '=')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    h1 = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class','report-wrapper'})
    for hack in h1:
      h2 = hack.find_all("div",attrs={"class","report"})
      for i in h2:
        layanan = i.find_all('b')[0].text.strip()
        report = i.find_all('a')[2].text.strip()
        bug_hunter = i.find_all('a')[1].text.strip()
        mirror = i.find("a", {"class": "title"})['href']
        date = i.find_all("div", {"class": "date"})
        for d in date:
          waktu = d.text
        data = {"Company": [layanan], "Title:": [report], "Submit:": [bug_hunter], "Link:": [mirror], "Date:": [waktu]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

my result only get 1 data, can you help me for get more data and save another file?

```
df.head()
```

| index | Company | Title: | Submit: | Link: | Date: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Reddit | Application level DOS at Login Page ( Accepts Long Password ) | e100_speaks | https://hackerone.com/reports/1168804 | 03 Feb 2022 |

Comment: What does "save another file?" is meaning in this context? Improving your question with details to this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Based on your questions code, you will overwrite your dataframe with every iteration, thats why you only get one result.

#### How to fix?

- Create an empty list before your loops
- Append all the extracted dicts to this list
- Create your dataframe based on that list of dicts

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = []
url = 'http://h1.nobbd.de/index.php?start='
for page in range(1,3):   
    req = requests.get(url + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    h1 = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class','report-wrapper'})
    for hack in h1:
        h2 = hack.find_all("div",attrs={"class","report"})
        for i in h2:
            layanan = i.find_all('b')[0].text.strip()
            report = i.find_all('a')[2].text.strip()
            bug_hunter = i.find_all('a')[1].text.strip()
            mirror = i.find("a", {"class": "title"})['href']
            date = i.find_all("div", {"class": "date"})
            for d in date:
                waktu = d.text
            data.append({'Company':[layanan], 'Title':[report], 'Submit':[hunter], 'link':[mirror], 'Date':[waktu]})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: thank you @hedgehog, this is work